# Arrangement with repetition and a specific amount in each set

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say that there's a bagel shop which has 4 varieties of bagels, and you're looking to buy 12 bagels.  But, You need to have at least one bagel from each variety. How many different ways can you select your 12 bagels?

The prof wants us to calculate this is two different ways, which I don't understand what's the difference between the two ways.

a) Count by arrangement with repetition
b) Count by selection (combination)

So I think I got part b down, here's my solution:
    We first pre-load each of the 4 varieties with 1 bagel, so there are 8 slots left to choose from, and we create 3 partitions in order to arrange the rest of the 8 bagels, so in total we'd have $8+3=11$ slots to arrange the rest of the bagels.  so, there are $11C3$ ways of ordering the rest of the bagels $=165$ ways.

Now for part a, which is asking to evaluate this scenario, but in a different manner which involves arrangements with repetition.  I don't know where to start with this one...  I can provide an example which uses this formula: $P(n; r_1+r_2+...+r_m)=\frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!..r_m!}$.  He showed us this formula in class for counting $n$ objects wit $r_1$ of type 1, $r_2$ of type 2, ... $r_m$ of type m.
Here's an example we did in class:"How many ways can 20 different diplomats be assigned to 5 different continents,  if each continent needs to have 4 diplomats each?"
We said that there are 5 objects to choose from, so $m=5$, and that each must have 4 diplomats each, so each of the continents will get exactly 4 diplomats, which works out perfectly since $\frac{20}{5}=4$, and hence the total number of ways using the formula above was $P(20;4,4,4,4,4)=\frac{20!}{(4!)^4}$
However in the question which we need to complete, we need to have at least 1 of each.  I'm stuck with how to start this :/
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you do it if you didn't have the "at least one of each" constraint?  If so, then just pull out one of each type, leaving you with the need to choose $8$ more with no such constraint.

Comment: if there wasn't the constraint of having at least one, the solution would simply be 12C4

Comment: No....That would be the number of ways to choose $4$ objects out of $12$.  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a useful method here.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did that wrong.  It would be 15C3

Comment: 12 bagels + 3 partitions = 15 total slots, and choose 3 of the slots

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Not sure about an obvious alternative method.  Well, $8$ is pretty small...so it isn't difficult to simply enumerate the cases.